# DataTables convert date JSON from Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use [Datadatables](https://www.datatables.net/) in server-side mode.
For the date my server return a JSON DATE mode for example:

```
"2015-12-18T17:04:27Z"
```

How can I format the DataTables localization automatically format of the language of the browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this "2015-12-18T17:04:27Z" is the value returned from the server, here is my take on it.

```
new Date("2015-12-18T17:04:27Z").toLocaleDateString() // =>"12/18/2015"
new Date("2015-12-18T17:04:27Z").toLocaleString() // => "12/18/2015, 12:04:27 PM"
```

There are a number of methods you could use to format it how you like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Note: The comments are the outputs determined by my *Locale*, yours may differ

Comment: That you! Now I need to understand how integrate it in datatables plugin.